# How to show default google maps Places icon in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Hy I have been working on the google maps api in android and I used Google maps places API to show some places on the maps with markers. And these all thing working fine for me.

But if we look the native google maps app, it shows the places itself with the default google icons.

so here is the picture display for an idea

[image: Google places with default icons]

but in my app I am having plain google map. Can I have view as we have in our default google maps application ?? please help

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It shows in simple map but it is depends on camera focus and this type of things availability near by your camera focus. check it another position and move it smoothly it will show.

Comment: yes. you are right. Can I show it always. I mean with zoom in and zoom out places must be shown always

Comment: I don't have any correct idea you can show over the map with zoom in/out mode.